# Styling issue for Developer Story tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface, developer-story

It seems like the Developer Story tab in the profile page doesn't have the underline below it:

[image]

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @Stéphane OS X El Capitan 10.11.5, Safari 9.1.1

Comment: I can't repro the bug, are you zoomed in/out in your browser?

Comment: @Stéphane Nope, it's normal size. However, it seems to occur in OS X Safari only, I can't reproduce it in iOS Safari

Comment: @Stéphane I can't reproduce this anymore, maybe it's fixed